# How do I set set values in multiple fields using awk?

Tags: awk

Say I have the following data in a file (file.txt):

```
one|two|three|four|five|six
```

And I want to prefix field one ($1) with an "A" and I want to prefix field three ($3) with a "B".  What would my awk script look like?  I tried:

```
awk -F "|" -OFS='|' '
   {
    $1 = "A"$1
    $3 = "B"$3
    print;
   }
' file.txt
```

But this didn't work.  The output was:

```
Aone|two|three|four|five|six  B
```

Sorry, I'm not great awk programmer here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I figured it out.  It had to do with the output field separator (OFS).  If I issue the following it works:

```
awk -F "|" 'BEGIN{OFS="|";}{$1="A"$1;$3="B"$3; print}' file.txt
```

The OFS value has to be inside the script and not passed as an parameter to awk.  Not exactly sure why.

Comment: You just had to use `-v OFS='|'` instead of `-OFS='|'` but the better approach would've been to set both variables at the same time (`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$1="A"$1; $3="B"$3;  print}' file.txt`) to avoid using the same hard-coded value (`"|"`) in 2 places.

Answer (score 0):

Using the flag `-OFS='|'` is setting the field separator to `S=|`.  Just do

```
awk '...' FS=\| OFS=\| file.txt
```